# Most number of items vs Most items

Tags: expressions

Consider this phrase, would you write this:

> The bucket containing the most items

or in this form:

> The bucket containing the most number of items

Some information here: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3439

Or would you suggest another form instead of "the most" ?

Comment: As [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+most+number+of%2Cthe+highest+number+of%2Cthe+greatest+number+of%2Cthe+largest+number+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20highest%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20greatest%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20largest%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0), the *average* Anglophone would not use the second form (they'd use *largest, greatest, highest*, but not normally *most*).

Comment: "_the most number_" sounds strange to me.

Comment: Wait, an excellently comprehensive (as always) Language Log post is your *starting point*, and your follow-up question to that is "would you write this", which you ask of a random bunch of strangers on the Internet, no less. I am really not quite sure what you are hoping to gain from that.

Comment: meh, 'the most number' is not particularly felicitous or common, but isn't totally a clunker and wouldn't be out of the ordinary in regular informal speech. But, yes, the first one is much better.

Comment: With @RegDwigнt here. The most appropriate answer to this may well consist of a link to that Language log post and quoting some main points: the construction is used, but is very, very rare. Most people would think it is wrong. But since you have the link already in your question... you have the answer to your question. Unless you want to ask something else?

Comment: Is one of your buckets above receiving a "largest capacity bucket award"? From your link, it appears the justification for the seemingly redundant usage is an award title.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes that bucket is going to have an award, sort of. But this is not the main point I think. Anyway I have edited the question, I am open to suggestion for other forms

Comment: Greatest or least number.  Most or fewest items.  Just as greatest volume but most cubic feet.  Most with a dimension is awkward, because it sets you up to hear the measure rather than the dimension.

Comment: There is no way in all the world the answer to this question is opinion-based.  This is a principle of usage taught in Junior High Schools.  Things that become plural take forms that indicate counting -- most and fewest, other things take forms that more directly indicate magnitude.  Fewer chairs, less furniture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greatest or least number. Most or fewest items.

Just as greatest volume but most cubic feet.  Lowest heat but fewest degrees.

Dimensions are singular like substances (length, water).  Measures are generally plural (feet, even when it is 0.97 feet).  So in the abstract, we use forms that go with the singular on the former and forms that go better with plurals on the latter.

'Most' with a dimension is awkward, because it sets you up to hear the measure (e.g. Liters) rather than the dimension (e.g. Volume).

While 'number' skirts the edge of being a dimension conceptually, it is one in practice.

Answer (score 3):

"Most" in this instance means "largest number of". "Most number" is therefore incorrect. "Most items" is correct. As "most" is improperly modifying "numbers" in the second example sentence it would be improved by using a different word. Either use  "most items" or "largest number of items."